# Explicit example of dimensional regularization involving $\gamma^5$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, regularization, dirac-matrices, dimensional-regularization

I'm currently reading Collins' book [Renormalization](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/renormalization/6EA5EEEBB9A02190F7C805856244181B), Chapter 4. In section 4.5 he introduces $\gamma$-matrices and the trace operation in an arbitrary dimension $d$. In section 4.6 he then talks about $\gamma^5$ and the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$.

I'm looking for an explicit calculation of dimensional regularization of an amplitude involving $\gamma^5$ in the 't Hooft-Veltman scheme. I think I can reproduce most of his results from the previously mentioned sections, but I wonder what one has to do if faced with an actual amplitude that needs to be calculated. I have a hard time finding explicit calculations --- everyone seems to talk about it, but most shy away from showing the calculation. Preferably with a reasonably simple example, i.e. a simple triangle-diagram.

Note: I have seen [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60825/) question and the corresponding answer, but once again, there is not really an explicit calculation anywhere...

Comment: Look in the appendix of https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3501

Comment: Have you seen 19.2 in Peskin Shroeder?